# "живущего в христианскую эру" or "живущего в христианской эре"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, винительный-падеж

Which one is correct and why?

"Это очень важно для любого человека, живущего в христианскую эру"

or

"Это очень важно для любого челoвека, живущего в христианской эре"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammatical case (Accusative) in the first sentence is correct and applicable to other adverbials of time: **в наше время**, **в наш век**, **в эпоху коммунизма**, **в старину**, **в понедельник - воскресенье**, **в первый год**.

In other adverbials of time however a more congruent Prepositional is employed: **в прошлом месяце**, **в будущем году**, **в январе - декабре**

There appears to be no universal rule to this. There're some principles of inflexion within adverbials which are applicable to select time denoting words.

More details in [Выражение времени: "Когда?"](https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/14659/)
*(www.ruspeach.com - Русский для иностранцев)*

Comment: I guess it might be related to the "filling" of timespan. Whether it is just a small speck on the span, or mostly all of it. Compare, "в тот год холодная погода...." and "в следующем году работаем по 9 часов в день". The second phrase has a shade of "all year through". And, human can hardly live all the era or epoch through.